# get the name of the Day from first day of the month in Moment.js

Tags: javascript, date, calendar, momentjs

I am trying to build a calendar in JS using Moment.js

I am trying to get the name of the first day of the month, or example ,

1.6.2018 is:"Friday"

I tried this but first date is becoming an object of the first day in month (), and I just don't know how to extract from this object the name of the day

```
{
    let date=;
    let firstDate;
    date=moment().format();
    console.log(date);
    firstDate=moment(date).startOf(`month`);
    console.log(firstDate)
    firstDate=moment(firstDate).date(1);
    console.log(firstDate);
}
```

maybe you have a better solution for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this to get the name of the first day of the current month:

```
moment().startOf('month').format('dddd');
```

Of course, this only gets you the first day for the **current** month, if you want to change the month, just call `.startOf('month').format('dddd')` on any other date/moment within the month you want.

Anyway, what you are looking for is `.format('dddd')` which will return the name of the day of a moment ;)

Answer (score 4):

If you do NOT want to bother with moment, you can just do this:

```js
console.log("Default:",
  new Date(2018,5,1).toLocaleDateString(undefined, { weekday: 'long' })
)

console.log("English:",
  new Date(2018,5,1).toLocaleDateString("en-US", { weekday: 'long' })
);


console.log("Hebrew:",
  new Date(2018,5,1).toLocaleDateString("he-IL", { weekday: 'long' })
)
```

Comment: If you set the language to *undefined*, the result will be in the browser default language. ;-)

Comment: [*ECMA-402*](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-402/1.0/#sec-6.2.4) says that if the locale is undefined, then it should use "*a … language tag for the host environment’s current locale*". It works fine for me when called as `new Date().toLocaleString(undefined, {weekday: 'long'})`.

Comment: Ah. I never passed undefined to anything before.

Comment: Yes, you have to pass the value *undefined*, you can't just elide it (I used to think that should work too). :-)